# How to take value from id then store it in another variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a value stored in id="ids", then I want to store that value in the reserve-id variable

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete" reserve-id='(id="ids")'>Delete</button>
```

How to do this?

So I will call this reserve-id here

```
$('.delete').click(function(){
        var reserve_id = $(this).attr('reserve-id');
        console.log(reserve_id)
    })
```

Comment: `console.log(document.querySelector("button").getAttribute("reserve-id"))`

Comment: Please be aware that `reserve-id` is not a valid custom attribute. Consider using `data-reserve-id` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use the data attribute

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete" data-reserve-id='(id="ids")'>Delete</button>

/*js*/
$('.delete').click(function(){
var reserve_id = $(this).data('reserve-id');
console.log(reserve_id)})
```

Comment: how do i get the value that is in id="ids"

Comment: I do not understand what you're talking about. Explain in more detail.